# How is submodules feature implemented internally if it uses tracking branch

Tags: git

I'm reading [this great article](http://www.speirs.org/blog/2009/5/11/understanding-git-submodules.html) on sub-modules which explains that the submodule is kept as a special kind of file in the master repository commit tree:

```
[/tmp/git/super(master)]$ git ls-files --stage 
100644 831cdc0dc1b88e69aa9943cf09907ae1bcd031fc 0   .gitmodules
160000 85ab8ba4edf9168ab051ded7ddbbe20861b71528 0   ProjectA     <--------
100644 16f5c2d3aa9656fc424352e4cfaa2523c809778b 0   super.txt
```

where `85ab8ba4edf9168ab051ded7ddbbe20861b71528` is the hash of the commit in the foreign/submodule repository.

If I use the approach with a tracking branch:

```
# add submodule to track master branch
git submodule add -b master [URL to Git repo];

# update your submodule
git submodule update --remote
```

How does it work internally?

As I understand:

- the tracking branch is setup in the submodule cloned repository
- the tracking branch is added to .gitmodules

But what happens to the special file referencing the commit? Does it still hold the commit hash from the submodule?

Is the tracking branch feature only affects the behavior when I run

```
git submodule update --remote
```

in that it checks the submodule tracking branch and checks out the new commit and updates the index of the master repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Background (feel free to skip to next section)

The main thing to remember about submodules is that there are always *two* Gits involved at the point where the submodule joins to the superproject.

The superproject has a minimum of three pieces of information.  Two are in `.gitmodules`:

- the full path, e.g., `path/to/ProjectA` (if the submodule is down in some set of sub-directories) or simply `ProjectA` (if the submodule resides at the top level); and
- the URL, so that Git can run `git clone ...` to obtain the submodule after you've cloned the superproject (but not its submodules).

The *index* (as seen with `git ls-files --stage` has two pieces of information:

- the full path, e.g., `path/to/projectA` (which must match the `.gitmodules` entry); and
- the commit hash you want, e.g., `85ab8ba4edf9168ab051ded7ddbbe20861b71528`.

Since these overlap, you can obviously get out of sync: if you change the path, things get a little weird.

The submodule itself is a Git repository, though.  That means that besides *commits*, it has a `HEAD`, branches, tags, and so on.  The contents of `HEAD` represent the *current commit*.  Initially, when the superproject controls everything, the submodule's Git is told: *Detach `HEAD` by checking out one specific commit by hash ID*, e.g., `85ab8ba4edf9168ab051ded7ddbbe20861b71528`.

You can go into the submodule, though, and check out a branch name, or a different tag.  You can run `git fetch` to obtain commits from that submodule Git's *usptream*, which is not related to the superproject.  You can, in short, do anything you can do in any old Git repository.

But once you do, things are out of sync: the commit ID to which `HEAD` resolves may not match the commit ID stored in the superproject.

#### Using branch names with submodules

> ```
> git submodule add -b master [URL to Git repo];
> ```
>
> ... the tracking branch is added to `.gitmodules`

Yes.  There it sits, waiting for your next command:

> ```
> git submodule update --remote
> ```

which fishes it out of there (or elsewhere<sup>1</sup>) and makes the Git handling the submodule run:

```
git fetch [potential additional options]
```

followed by one of `git merge`, `git rebase`, or `git checkout`, depending on more flags and options and settings.  The arguments passed to the next command also depends on more flags and options and settings.

Once that's done, the submodule itself probably has some other commit checked out.  That is, `git rev-parse HEAD`, run in the submodule, names something other than `85ab8ba...`.  So now your superproject and subproject are out of sync: your superproject calls for commit `85ab8ba...` specifically, but your submodule isn't "on" that commit.

It's now your job to make sure that the superproject works correctly with that new submodule hash in place.  If so, you can—while in the superproject—run `git add` on the submodule's path.  This updates the special index entry, keeping the path intact but writing a new commit hash into it.

Now you can `git commit` in the superproject.  The contents of the index, as usual, determine the contents of the new commit.  The commit will record the new hash ID.  The contents of `.gitmodules`, containing the branch name, have not changed, so the version of `.gitmodules` recorded in the new commit is the same as the version of `.gitmodules` recorded in the old commit.  The only sign of the new hash ID in the superproject is that the hash ID stored in the commit (to be copied back to the index on `git checkout` of that commit in the superproject repository) is this updated one.

---

<sup>1</sup>The branch used at this point is taken from `.gitmodules` *unless* there's a `submodule.<name>.branch` setting in `$GIT_DIR/config`.  The config setting overrides the `.gitmodules` setting.  The `<name>` part of this is the current branch name *in the superproject*.  All of these various things need qualification, because we're looking at two Gits simultaneously: the superproject Git repo, and the submodule Git repo.

(The existing Git documentation seems to be not-so-great about maintaining clear distinctions here.)

Comment: thanks, great answer as usual :). so it seems that I could manually do what git does if I use a branch name with submodule - go inside the submodule repository and run git fetch and git checkout <branchname>. Is it correct? And it's in both cases I have to manually do `git add path/to/submodule`, right?

Comment: also two follow-up questions: is the tracking branch inside the submodule relevant? and this configuration `submodule.<name>.branch` is for all modules? is its purpose to sync all submodules with a current branch in the superproject?

Comment: and one slightly offtopic question - have you used git subtree? I'm now considering splitting pretty large project and thinking about using either submodules or subtree. I've read the comparison, I'm interested in your take on this. Thanks

Comment: To answer the last question first, I don't really like *any* of the options. Submodules themselves make sense in a sort of design-y way, but prove painful in practice. Subtree seems more practical in a sense, but is still a pain. What I have used in practice is simply "multiple repos, loosely synced, with a common tag across all the repos when it matters." That said, it seems like the submodule support has improved a lot since the bad old (git 1.5-1.7) days, and it might be worth trying again.

Comment: As for the rest: yes, you can manually do what the new options automate somewhat (that's how we used to do it...). Any upstream setting within the submodule matters when you are working inside the submodule, but not as much when you're not (I haven't used the newfangled modes in practice). I'm not really sure what the `submodule.<name>.branch` stuff is *for*; again, this all post-dates my bad experience with old style submodules.

Comment: I see, thanks. I just want to split backend repo which is huge and code is Java from front-end. Backend guys won't be working with front-end and vice verse. The front-end should be part of back-end repo only when the main build runs on TeamCity so I'm thinking that subtree is a better option to integrate front-end repo into backend

Comment: btw, [here is](https://blog.angularindepth.com/become-a-git-pro-by-learning-git-architecture-in-15-minutes-9c995db6faeb) the article I've written about git internals  that is pretty popular